# Extracting object from JSON and rebuild a new JSON in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have a blob of JSON which I get back from the server and I'm trying to get a specific obj and use it in a new JSON that I need to send it back.

JSON:

```
var oldJson =  {"Message":"string","Balance":0,"OrderId":94,"SiteId":1234,"OrderLine":[{"Id":"e672f84e-4b97-4cd7-826a-d0e57247ffe3","Product":{"Id":21,"Codes":["1112"],"Sku":"CS1112"},"Description":"testing 123","QuantityRequired":1,"QuantityPicked":0,"SourceSite":{"Id":1,"PropertyCode":"","StoreCode":"1"},"Status":"Preparing","TotalOriginalValue":0,"TotalAdjustedValue":0,"AdjustmentReference":null,"Note":null,"PromotionLines":[],"Taxes":[],"CancellationReason":null,"QuantityIssued":0,"TotalPaidAmount":null,"CustomData":{}},{"Id":"c9f18678-11f0-4fbb-afe4-db926ae97d04","Product":{"Id":9,"Codes":["1113"],"Sku":"CS1113"},"Description":"testing 123","QuantityRequired":1,"QuantityPicked":0,"SourceSite":{"Id":1,"PropertyCode":"","StoreCode":"1"},"Status":"Preparing","TotalOriginalValue":0,"TotalAdjustedValue":0,"AdjustmentReference":null,"Note":null,"PromotionLines":[],"Taxes":[],"CancellationReason":null,"QuantityIssued":0,"TotalPaidAmount":null,"CustomData":{}}],"CustomData":{}}
```

I want to get the `Product` object with the key name, I managed to get the obj but without its key name `Product`

I tried the code below, its giving me the Product key name but the data in it are the same product (which is wrong). Also how can I add extra object when you push the data in the array?

So it would look like this:

```
"Product": { "Id": 21, "Codes": ["1112"], "Sku": "1112" }, "TotalValue": 0, "Quantity": 1

var obj = {}
var el = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldJson.OrderLine.length; i++) {
    obj["Product"] = json.OrderLine[i].Product;
    el.push(obj);
}
```

Trying to rebuild the same JSON but with just the `Product` in the `OrderLine`.

```
var rebuild = {
  "Message": "string",
  "Balance": 0,
  "OrderId": 10,
  "SiteId": 1234,
  "OrderLine": el,
  "CustomData": {}
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
        "Message": "string",
        "Balance": 0,
        "OrderId": 10,
        "SiteId": 1234,
        "OrderLine": [
            {
                "Product": { "Id": 21, "Codes": ["1112"], "Sku": "1112" }, "TotalValue": 0, "Quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "Product": { "Id": 9, "Codes": ["1113"], "Sku": "1113" }, "TotalValue": 0, "Quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        "CustomData": {}
    }
```

Here's a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mestrada/Lz3v9psp/2/)

Comment: Use json.parse , then modify the object, then convert it back to json usin stringify

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @void I edited my question with expected result.

Comment: @MrNew yea check the answer.

Comment: @MrNew see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to use `.map` and fetch products

```
var product = json.OrderLine.map(function(el){
    return {"Product": el.Product, "TotalValue":el.TotalValue, "Quantity":el.Quantity};
});

var rebuild = {
  "Message": "string",
  "Balance": 0,
  "OrderId": 10,
  "SiteId": 1234,
  "OrderLine": product,
  "CustomData": {}
}
```

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz3v9psp/5/)

Comment: Oh didn't think of `.map`, but how can I add the rest of the object like the `"TotalValue:0, "Quantity": 1`

Comment: Nvm found it, sorry was being slow. @madalinivascu Yeah saw your answer.

Comment: how can you do it if using `for()`?

Comment: @MrNew see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following each loop:

```js
var json = {
  "Message": "string",
  "Balance": 0,
  "OrderId": 94,
  "SiteId": 1234,
  "OrderLine": [{
      "Id": "e672f84e-4b97-4cd7-826a-d0e57247ffe3",
      "Product": {
        "Id": 21,
        "Codes": [
          "1112"
        ],
        "Sku": "CS1112"
      },
      "Description": "testing 123",
      "QuantityRequired": 1,
      "QuantityPicked": 0,
      "SourceSite": {
        "Id": 1,
        "PropertyCode": "",
        "StoreCode": "1"
      },
      "Status": "Preparing",
      "TotalOriginalValue": 0,
      "TotalAdjustedValue": 0,
      "AdjustmentReference": null,
      "Note": null,
      "PromotionLines": [

      ],
      "Taxes": [

      ],
      "CancellationReason": null,
      "QuantityIssued": 0,
      "TotalPaidAmount": null,
      "CustomData": {

      }
    },
    {
      "Id": "c9f18678-11f0-4fbb-afe4-db926ae97d04",
      "Product": {
        "Id": 9,
        "Codes": [
          "1113"
        ],
        "Sku": "CS1113"
      },
      "Description": "testing 123",
      "QuantityRequired": 1,
      "QuantityPicked": 0,
      "SourceSite": {
        "Id": 1,
        "PropertyCode": "",
        "StoreCode": "1"
      },
      "Status": "Preparing",
      "TotalOriginalValue": 0,
      "TotalAdjustedValue": 0,
      "AdjustmentReference": null,
      "Note": null,
      "PromotionLines": [

      ],
      "Taxes": [

      ],
      "CancellationReason": null,
      "QuantityIssued": 0,
      "TotalPaidAmount": null,
      "CustomData": {

      }
    }
  ],
  "CustomData": {

  }
}
$.each(json.OrderLine, function(i, v) {
  json.OrderLine[i] = {"product":v.Product,"TotalValue": v.TotalOriginalValue, "Quantity": v.QuantityRequired}
});

console.log(json)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or using for loop:

```js
var json = {
  "Message": "string",
  "Balance": 0,
  "OrderId": 94,
  "SiteId": 1234,
  "OrderLine": [{
      "Id": "e672f84e-4b97-4cd7-826a-d0e57247ffe3",
      "Product": {
        "Id": 21,
        "Codes": [
          "1112"
        ],
        "Sku": "CS1112"
      },
      "Description": "testing 123",
      "QuantityRequired": 1,
      "QuantityPicked": 0,
      "SourceSite": {
        "Id": 1,
        "PropertyCode": "",
        "StoreCode": "1"
      },
      "Status": "Preparing",
      "TotalOriginalValue": 0,
      "TotalAdjustedValue": 0,
      "AdjustmentReference": null,
      "Note": null,
      "PromotionLines": [

      ],
      "Taxes": [

      ],
      "CancellationReason": null,
      "QuantityIssued": 0,
      "TotalPaidAmount": null,
      "CustomData": {

      }
    },
    {
      "Id": "c9f18678-11f0-4fbb-afe4-db926ae97d04",
      "Product": {
        "Id": 9,
        "Codes": [
          "1113"
        ],
        "Sku": "CS1113"
      },
      "Description": "testing 123",
      "QuantityRequired": 1,
      "QuantityPicked": 0,
      "SourceSite": {
        "Id": 1,
        "PropertyCode": "",
        "StoreCode": "1"
      },
      "Status": "Preparing",
      "TotalOriginalValue": 0,
      "TotalAdjustedValue": 0,
      "AdjustmentReference": null,
      "Note": null,
      "PromotionLines": [

      ],
      "Taxes": [

      ],
      "CancellationReason": null,
      "QuantityIssued": 0,
      "TotalPaidAmount": null,
      "CustomData": {

      }
    }
  ],
  "CustomData": {

  }
}


for (var i = 0; i < json.OrderLine.length; i++) {
  json.OrderLine[i] = {
    "product": json.OrderLine[i].Product,
    "TotalValue": json.OrderLine[i].TotalOriginalValue,
    "Quantity": json.OrderLine[i].QuantityRequired
  }
}
console.log(json)
```

Comment: how can you do it if using `for()`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried using it to another JSON when I put `var xd = json...` in the `for()` and tried to use it use it somewhere else, its only giving me 1 product. https://jsfiddle.net/mestrada/Lz3v9psp/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lz3v9psp/7/ or https://jsfiddle.net/Lz3v9psp/8/ learn some js first man then ask questions here

Comment: got it fixed before your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can access object using key.. Try this

```
var product = $.map(oldJson, function (data, key) {
            if (key == "OrderLine") return data;
        });
```

Comment: Why to unnecessary use jQuery when it's easily doable by vanilla JS?